# checking whether a word from a vector appears in the same row in different columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply, grepl

I am trying to troubleshoot my data, and check whether a certain name appears in two different columns in the same row (same observation):

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  text1 = c("John Jay Jakson",
            "John Jay Jakson",
            "John Jay Jakson",
            "John Jack Jakson"), 
  text2 = c("Jerry Jack Jameson", 
            "Jerry Jack Jameson", 
            "Jerry Jack Jameson", 
            "Jerry Jack Jameson"))

df2 <- data.frame(
  names = c("John", "Jay", "Jackson", "Jerry", "Jack", "Jameson"))
```

The code I've come up with is the following

```
data.check = sapply(df2$names, function(x) (grepl(x, df1$text1) & grepl(x, df1$text2))==TRUE)
```

or alternatively:

```
which(sapply(df2$names, function(x) (grepl(x, df1$text1) & grepl(x, df1$text2))==TRUE))
```

But these are not the best ways to sift through the data. Instead, I want to have a new column in df1, df1$check, that holds a 1/0 based on whether each row has the same name in that row under df1$text1 and df1$text2.

I know that assigning this code to a new column won't work:

```
df1$check = sapply(df2$names, function(x) (grepl(x, df1$text1) & grepl(x, df1$text2))==TRUE)
```

it gives me false for the 4th row, which should be a true.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `sapply` in the OP's code returns a logical `matrix`.

```
> sapply(df2$names, function(x) (grepl(x, df1$text1) & grepl(x, df1$text2)))
      John   Jay Jackson Jerry  Jack Jameson
[1,] FALSE FALSE   FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE   FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE   FALSE FALSE FALSE   FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE   FALSE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE
```

Each column of the `matrix` should be converged to a single logical value to create a vector.  We may wrap with `rowSums` on the logical matrix and then convert the row wise sum to logical vector (`> 0`) and coerce it back to binary (`+` - `TRUE` -> 1, `FALSE` -> 0)

```
df1$check <- +(rowSums(sapply(df2$names, function(x) 
     (grepl(x, df1$text1) & grepl(x, df1$text2)))) > 0)
df1$check
[1] 0 0 0 1
```

---

Or another option is to loop with `lapply`, return a `list` and use `Reduce` with `|` to return a vector

```
df1$check <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df2$names, function(x)
      (grepl(x, df1$text1) & grepl(x, df1$text2)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I include a dplyr approach:

```
# import required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# create your data (I added two more rows)
df1 <- data.frame(
  text1 = c("John Jay Jakson",
            "John Jay Jakson",
            "John Jay Jakson",
            "John Jack Jakson","Peter","John Snow"),
  text2 = c("Jerry Jack Jameson", 
            "Jerry Jack Jameson", 
            "Jerry Jack Jameson", 
            "Jerry Jack Jameson","Peter", "Clay Snow"))

df2 <- data.frame(
  names = c("John", "Jay", "Jackson", "Jerry", "Jack", "Jameson"))

# optionally convert df2 to vector or list
v2<-as.vector(df2$names)

#use of str_detect() to look for the string
# use of case_when() that works like if/else
# by including the | operator between the different names
# create a new column called check to store 1s and 0s  

df1<-df1%>%
  mutate(check=case_when(str_detect(text1,paste(v2, collapse = "|"))==TRUE & str_detect(text2,paste(v2, collapse = "|"))==TRUE ~"1",
                         TRUE~"0"))
```